# How to convert a string month name into month number in SQL

Tags: mysql

How can I convert a string name into the actual month number. For instance if I have a string as 'March', how can this be converted to 3.

I know that this can be done using a case statement but then I want to know if there is any predefined function that can do this conversion.

Comment: See the manual.

Comment: Please give us a query or at least some context.  It is an unusual request to ask for how to convert a string month by itself (with no day or year) into a number.

Comment: Users can enter their month name as criteria in a text box. The text box has validation to verify that the full month name has been entered. What I want to do is convert this text into its number and proceed.

Also, am not sure if the bigger picture of my query will help answer this part of my problem. The problem itself seems very standalone.

Answer (score 1):

```
select date_format(str_to_date('March','%M'),'%c')
```

firstly, using str_to_date to convert string to month name, and then format the month name to number format

Comment: A code-only answer with no explanation is not recommended.

Comment: does not work in mysql

Answer (score 0):

month(str_to_date(`MonthField`,'%M'))

For more information about `month` and `str_to_date`, you can check the [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

example for above is `select month(str_to_date('March','%M')) from dual;`
will give the result `3`

Comment: Please, add an explanation. See [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: does not work in mysql

Answer (score -1):

Use the STRING_TO_DATE function:

```
SELECT STRING_TO_DATE('March','%M')
```

See the (function reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

See the [date formatting codes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) reference.